# R:Montecarlo simulation using transition matrix

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo

I have a transition matrix :

```
a
           A          B         C     D         E          F          G          H         I
A 0.00000000 0.66666667 0.0000000 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.0000000
B 0.08823529 0.02941176 0.2941176 0.000 0.2352941 0.05882353 0.02941176 0.11764706 0.1470588
C 0.00000000 0.37500000 0.0000000 0.000 0.4166667 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.08333333 0.1250000
D 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.3333333 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.0000000
E 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.2307692 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.07692308 0.1923077
F 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000 0.5000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.5000000
G 0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0000000 0.500 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
H 0.00000000 0.27272727 0.3636364 0.000 0.1818182 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.1818182
I 0.00000000 0.31250000 0.1875000 0.125 0.3125000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.06250000 0.0000000
```

and i have in my dataset a categorical  variable :

```
state=c("G" ,"I" ,"G", "C", "D", "I","A" ,"G", "G" ,"H", "C", "D" ,"C", "H" "F", "B", "F" ,"G" ,"D", "E" ,"B" ,"H" ,"E" ,"C" ,"F" ,"H", "C", "H" ,"F" ,"H")
```

and now i want to use my transition matrix to simulate a variable just like my variable `state` using the Monte carlo approach.
Can you advise me which R package or function can help me to do my simulation please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `markovchainSequence` from package `markovchain`. Example:

```
mat <- as.matrix(read.table(text="
0.00000000 0.66666667 0.0000000 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.0000000
0.08823529 0.02941176 0.2941176 0.000 0.2352941 0.05882353 0.02941176 0.11764706 0.1470588
0.00000000 0.37500000 0.0000000 0.000 0.4166667 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.08333333 0.1250000
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.3333333 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.33333333 0.33333333 0.0000000
0.00000000 0.50000000 0.2307692 0.000 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.07692308 0.1923077
0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000 0.000 0.5000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.5000000
0.00000000 0.50000000 0.0000000 0.500 0.0000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.0000000
0.00000000 0.27272727 0.3636364 0.000 0.1818182 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.1818182
0.00000000 0.31250000 0.1875000 0.125 0.3125000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.06250000 0.000000",
           header=FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
rownames(mat) <- colnames(mat) <- LETTERS[1:9]
mat[,9] <- 1-rowSums(mat[,1:8]) #To make sure your rows sum to 1

statesNames <- LETTERS[1:9]
markovchain_object <- new("markovchain", states = statesNames, transitionMatrix = mat)

markovchainSequence(n=10, markovchain = markovchain_object)

 [1] "C" "H" "C" "E" "C" "B" "C" "E" "B" "G"
```